# How to remove a certain symbol for a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, awk

I have a bash script where I get the disk usage, for example `60%`. How can I remove the `%` symbol? Using grep or awk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sed 's/%//'
```

Pipe your string through it for the best results.

Comment: There's a "g" missing because otherwise it would only match the first % in each line. So make it 's/%//g'.

Comment: @joechip: If there's only one `%`, as per the question, you don't need `g`.

Answer (score 12):

There is no need for external tools like `tr`or even `sed` as bash can do it on its own since forever.

```
percentage="60%"
number=${percentage%\%}
```

This statement removes the shortest matching substring (in this case an escaped `%`) from the end of the variable. There are other string manipulating facilities built into bash. It even supports regular expressions. Generally, most of the stuff you normally see people using `tr`, `sed`, `awk` or `grep` for can be done using a bash builtin. It's just almost noody knows about that and brings the big guns...

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSOREX1 for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of sed, use tr.

```
tr -d '%'
```

Comment: Good point (+1). `tr` is faster than `sed`.

Answer (score 4):

sed is one of the easiest ways

```
sed -i 's/\%//g' fileName
```

Answer (score 2):

If the disk usage is in a variable, bash can do the removal as part of a variable substitution:

```
diskusagepct="60%"
echo "disk usage: ${diskusagepct%\%} percent"  # prints disk usage: 60 percent
diskusagenum="${diskusagepct%\%}"  # sets diskusagenum to 60
```